# making the axis labels in jqplot clickable

Tags: jquery, jqplot

How can I make the axis labels (of a category X axis) clickable.

If it is less problematic, it is OK that the click will lead to a new link (and not some javascript code)

Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks, Boaz.

Comment: can you please specify expected behavior? thanks

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what Boaz is looking for, but I am using CategoryAxisRenderer and hoping to have the labels be hyperlinks to other parts of my site.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple script:

```
$(".jqplot-xaxis-label")
    .css({
        cursor: "pointer",
        zIndex: "1"
    })
    .click(function(){ location.href = "http://google.com"; });
```

The most important thing happening above is that the `zIndex` is being set to 1 so that it sits above the canvas object. Now you can actually click it. The `cursor` style just makes it have that friendly rollover mouse icon. Now, you can do whatever you want inside the click event.

Comment: change .jqplot-xaxis-label to .jqplot-table-legend for bar charts for example. works fine in current version

Answer (score 2):

My answer is almost similar to [Abishai Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/796739/abishai-gray) the difference being that it works with latest version of jqPlot
(Version tested: 1.0.4)

The CSS class for Axis ticks now end with -tick instead of -label

```
$('.jqplot-xaxis-tick')
    .css({ cursor: "pointer", zIndex: "1" })
    .click(function () { alert('Axis Tick Clicked'); });
```

Comment: I need to get the value of the label they click on, but I have not been able to figure out way to do that. Anyone know how I can get that in the click handler?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you expect as behavior after clicking category

Generator of Ticks is in file called: `jqplot.axisTickRenderer.js`

You can
1) modify the code to give every tick `#id` and attach behavior with your own jquery code

2) list ticks in `$(".jqplot-xaxis")` and add behavior -| |-