# How to enable click event for y axis ticks (label) in horizontal bar chart using Jqplot

Tags: jqplot

I am trying to implement the horizontal bar chart using jqplot.I want to enable click event for the y axis labels.

But i tried it with the jquery using class name to get access of "y axis ticks" .

```
  $('.jqplot-yaxis-tick').click(function ()
    {
       alert("you have clicked the label");

    });
```

Is there any event to do this like "jqplotDataClick" event in jqplot?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved
[From Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959942/making-the-axis-labels-in-jqplot-clickable)

just update the z-index of the .jqplot-yaxis-tick so it would be the first div to be clicked and added .live (or .on)

```
$('.jqplot-yaxis-tick').css({
            cursor: "pointer",
            zIndex: "200"
    }).live('click', function (e) {
        alert("you have clicked the label");
    });
```